# load over 1M rows to PrimeNG table

Tags: sql-server, angular, angular6, primeng

i am using PrimeNg table, and trying to figure how to use the [LazyLoad](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/lazy) event, in order to load each time X of rows,

### HTML

```
<p-table #dt
         [value]="workers"
         [columns]="cols"
         [paginator]="true"
         [rows]="pageSize"
         selectionMode="multiple"
         [lazy]="true"
         (onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)"
         [pageLinks]="3"
         [loading]="loading"
         [totalRecords]="totalRecords"
         >

  <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
    <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
      <button type="button" pButton iconPos="left" label="All Data" (click)="dt.exportCSV()" style="float:left"></button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
        {{col.header}}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-worker>
    <tr>
      <td>{{worker.firstName}}</td>
      <td>{{worker.lastName}}</td>
      <td>{{worker.gender}}</td>
      <td>{{worker.salary | number: '.2'}}</td>
      <td>{{worker.dateOfBirth}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

### TS

```
loadLazy(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    this.loading = true;
  //event.first = First row offset
  //event.rows = Number of rows per page

    var page = (event.first / this.pageSize) + 1;
    this.getData(event.first, event.rows) 
}

getData(first, rows) {
debugger;
this._srv.getEmployees().subscribe(data => {          
  this.workers = data.slice(first, (first + rows));
  this.loading = false;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.workers));
  }, error => {
    console.log('error:', JSON.stringify(error));
  }, () => {
    console.log('Completed getting data.')
  });
}
```

### SQL

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pagination]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pageNumber INT = 1  ,  -- default to 1
    @RowsPerPage INT = 10   -- default to 10
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [Workers]
    ORDER BY Id
            OFFSET ( ( @pageNumber - 1 ) * @RowsPerPage ) ROWS
                 FETCH NEXT @RowsPerPage ROWS ONLY;
END
```

The are over 1M records exist in "Workers" table and they are arriving fine,

why is the pagination is set to only 1 page?

if i want the real number of pages appear- i then need to load all the rows- thing that will take time, or even "break" the app?

How can I query for x pages on each time the user clicks on page in the pagination + to show the actual number of pages + display a label that show total number of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see "totalRecords" variable, but you have to set it.

If pageSize is 10 and you're showing 10 records, paginator will be set to 1.

If you set "totalRercords=1M", paginator will be set to 1M/10;